# What's the easiest way to use SQLite with SAS?

Tags: sqlite, sas

I want to investigate how to access SQLite DB from SAS. What's the easiest way of doing this? Is there a SAS product that we can license to do that? I don't want to use ODBC drivers as that seems to have been written a long time ago and is not officially part of SQLite.

Comment: Let me see if I get this...the SQLite ODBC driver is not officially part of SQLite, so you want to look if you can pay money to SAS so they can give you something just like an ODBC driver for SQLite that is...well, also not officially part of SQLite? 

Seriously, I don't see any problem using a third party product, as long as the indications that the product is used by enough people is strong enough. 

If you still feel uncomfortable with that, I would probably suggest to export the data from SQLite to some platform that you do feel  comfortable with.

Comment: I agree.  Export the data from SQLite database to something you can access in a way you're happy with.  SAS has (or had, anyways-long time no SAS) connectors for dozens of data sources.

Comment: Or use a generic ODBC driver. You can look at ConnectionStrings.com to see if anyone's already solved your setup - I see 6 references for SQLite.

Answer (score 6):

SAS supports reading data from pipes (in a unix environment).  Essentially, you can set up a filename statement to execute an sqlite command in the host environment, then process the command output as if reading it from a text file.

SAS Support page: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#pipe.htm

Example:

```
*----------------------------------------------
* (1) Write a command in place of the file path
*     --> important: the 'pipe' option makes this work
*----------------------------------------------;

filename QUERY pipe 'sqlite3 database_file "select * from table_name"';



*----------------------------------------------
* (2) Use a datastep to read the output from sqlite
*----------------------------------------------;

options linesize=max; *to prevent truncation of results;

data table_name;

   infile QUERY delimiter='|' missover dsd lrecl=32767;

   length 
      numeric_id 8
      numeric_field 8
      character_field_1 $40
      character_field_2 $20
      wide_character_field $500
   ;

   input
      numeric_id 
      numeric_field $
      character_field_1 $
      character_field_2 $
      wide_character_field $
   ;

run;



*----------------------------------------------
* (3) View the results, process data etc.
*----------------------------------------------;

proc contents;
proc means;
proc print;
run;
```